# Angular Routing Error as 'EmployeeCntrl' is not registered

Tags: angularjs

Here why i'm getting Error as 'EmployeeCntrl' is not registered.

**MyApp.js**

```
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-route.js" />
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])
    app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.msg = "This is MyApp....";
    })

    app.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
        .when('/Employee', {
            templateUrl: '/Html/Employee/Employee.html',
            controller: 'EmployeeCntrl'

        })
        .when('/Contact', {
            controller:'ContactCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/Html/Contact/Employee.js'
        })
    })
```

**Maserpage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head >
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Script/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Script/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Script/MyApp.js"></script>
    <link href="../CSS/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller='HomeCtrl'>
   <!--// {{msg}}-->

    <div id="RightDiv" class="">
        <a href="#!/Employee">Employee</a><br />
        <a href="#!/Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is My Employee.js code Here i implemented `EmployeeCntrl` which is comming from MyApp.js
**Employee.js**

```
/// <reference path="F:\DesignPattern\WebApi\Client\Script/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="F:\DesignPattern\WebApi\Client\Script/angular-route.js" />
/// <reference path="F:\DesignPattern\WebApi\Client\Script/MyApp.js" />

app.controller('EmployeeCntrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Emp="Hello Employee..."
})
```

Here I implemented Employee.js Code

**Employee.html**

```
<script src="Employee.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="EmployeeCntrl">
    <p>This is Employee</p>
    {{Emp}}
</div>
```

Comment: Don't need put `ng-controller="EmployeeCntrl"` in template. also remove `ng-controller='HomeCtrl'` from `Maserpage`

Comment: You need to include Employee.js in the index.html

Comment: EvenSame Error  As EmployeeCntrl is not Reg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already defining the controller for the templates in the config, its not necessary to again mention in the template.

Also it is better to refer your necessary controller files in the masterpage itself.

```
  <link href="../CSS/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="../../Script/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Script/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Script/MyApp.js"></script>
   <script src="Employee.js"></script>
```

Comment: But Sajeethram Employee Should be come in Demand...Even When i did modification as per urs also not working

Comment: Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'EmployeeCntrl' is not registered.

Comment: check your network tab if your controller reference is getting loaded

Comment: Yes it Loading And Also its shows That page but {{msg}} not defiding

Comment: No Sajeee Bhai Same Error

Answer (score 1):

**First add `Employee.js` to `root html file`.**

**Masterpage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head >
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Script/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Script/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Script/MyApp.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Script/Employee.js"></script>
    <link href="../CSS/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller='HomeCtrl'>
   <!--// {{msg}}-->

    <div id="RightDiv" class="">
        <a href="#!/Employee">Employee</a><br />
        <a href="#!/Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second, since you have taken controller reference in route, no need to take in html seperately,**

**Employee.html**

```
<div>
    <p>This is Employee</p>
    {{Emp}}
</div>
```

Comment: make sure, your `Employee.js ` loads after `MyApp.js`